# Limit characters in xticks pandas bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, formatting

I have the following code:

```
    df = input_df_.loc[input_df_.index.isin(inds)]
    df = df.drop(expected_metrics+metrics+['AgeNBR'],axis=1).mean()\
            .sort_values(ascending=False)[:25]
    df.plot(kind='bar',width=.4,position=1,color='red')
    full_df = input_df_[df.index].mean()
    full_df.plot(kind='bar',width=.4,position=0,color='blue')

    plt.show()

    difference = full_df - df

    difference.plot(kind='bar',color =  ['r' if x > 0 else 'b' for x in difference.values])
    plt.show()
```

the code works, but the two images end up super far away since some of the x-ticks are very long. Is there a way to limit the size of the text in individual x-ticks? Something like the first 7 characters?

Comment: Please do not add an answer to your question. An answer is an answer and should be added as answer. Apart your approach works only for categorical plots, while the other answers work for any kind of plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how the questioner solved this problem:

```
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    df.plot(kind='bar',width=.4,position=1,color='red')
    full_df = input_df_[df.index].mean()
    full_df.plot(kind='bar',width=.4,position=0,color='blue')\
        .set_xticklabels([str(tick)[:45] for tick in full_df.index])
    plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.gca().set_title('Selected and full feature set averages',fontsize=30)

    plt.subplot(1,2,2)     
    difference = df - full_df 

    difference.plot(kind='bar',color =  ['r' if x > 0 else 'b' for x in difference.values]).\
        set_xticklabels([str(tick)[:45] for tick in difference.index])
    plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.gca().set_title('Selected minus full feature set averages', fontsize=30)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: **.set_xticklabels([str(tick)[:45] for tick in full_df.index])**    works, but has the side effect of printing a tuple of index besides the plot... at least in my version of the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to shorten label text like:

```
...
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(item.get_text()[:10] for item in ax.get_xticklabels())
...
```

After that procedure your labels were store 10 symbols.

Answer (score 0):

you can acsses the x ticks using:

```
locs, labels = xticks()
```

then you can iterate over the labels and only show the first 7 characters with:

```
for label in labels:
label=label[:7]
```